# C# .Net 3.5 Can't type ']' in toolstrip text box

Tags: c#, non-ascii-characters, toolstrip

Good morning,
I have a winform application which includes:

1. Main Form with a toolstrip menu and a toolstrip bar
2. Inside the main form, a tab control, where each tab contains a toolstrip bar with a toolstrip text box

I need to enter text in the toolstrip text box, even with special character. My problem is, when I try to digit the ] character, using Alt Gr + (Italian keyboard), rather than add the character to the toolstrip textbox, the application move the focus on the button of the toolstrip bar of the main form.
Other characters ([, @, #) works fine.
Hope somebody can help.
Thank you.

Comment: Does it happens after pressing alt key alone? A workaround would be to copy that character from somewhere else and use ctr-v to paste.

Comment: For those who doesnot have italian keyboard, what is the other symbols on the button that contins "]"?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, pressing the AltGr alone does nothing. The strange thing is that it happens using AltGr with apparently random keys (O, I, +, but not @, #, L). Of course copying and pasting the character works fine, but is not an acceptable solution, since it forces the user to open something else to type or find the character

Comment: @Aspirin: here's the keyboard layouts: http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts